# To Remove the latest commit from gitlab repo not possible and removing old local commits

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to achieve two things. First to remove a useless commit that I pushed to gitlab. Second, remove all the old commits from my pc (but they have to remain on gitlab).

First I deleted the old .git dir. Then I did:

```
git init
git add .
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:asmf2/asmfrt.git
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

that produced

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
>   Use '--' to separate paths from revisions

How can I add it to the working tree? Anything else shall be done then?

And then, after removing the latest commit from gitlab, how can keep my pc without old commits. It will be enough to just modify the code, add the content, create a commit for it and then push to gitlab?

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way Git is designed to be used (but see *shallow clones* at the end).

The *intent* of a Git repository is to have *everything at your fingertips at all times.*  If you take your laptop with you camping, or on an airplane, or to the south pole, or whatever, you will have *everything*.

This means you never throw away commits, and in fact, Git is designed so that when you bring two Gits near each other and let them talk, they tend to give each other *every commit they have that the other doesn't*.  Git is constantly trying to [Borg up](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Borg) all the commits.

Of course, it *is* possible to throw out a commit, despite this design.  How hard it is depends on how many Gits have it.  If your Git is the *only* Git that has it, that makes it a lot easier.  As soon as your Git gives it to another Git, well ... if your Git gave it to Bob's Git, and Bob's Git has had relations with Carol's, Carol's has it now too.  If her Git had relations with Dave's, now Dave's got it as well!

So:

> I am trying to ... remove a useless commit that I pushed to gitlab.

You *can* do this, *provided* no one else's Git has contacted the Git at your Gitlab server.  But, unless you can log in directly to your Gitlap server, removing your repository won't help.  The first thing you will need to do is re-clone so that you have the whole thing again.

Once you re-clone, *then* you can use `git reset` to deliberately discard one commit.  That only discards it from *your* clone, so next, you must use a "force push"—a push that has the force of a command, rather than the gentleness of a polite request—to the Git on your Gitlab server, telling it to set *its* branch back similarly.  While you're doing that, if Bob and Carol and Dave exist—essentially, if anyone else has picked up the commit you want gone—you'll need to contact them somehow and request that they remove the commit from *their* Gits.  Once it's really gone from every Git, it won't keep re-infecting everyone.

It's up to the Gitlab server to decide whether they will obey this command.  If they *won't*, you can't get rid of the commit this way.  You really will have to log in directly to the server.

(In this case, once you are logged in to the server, you can navigate to the Git repository there and use `git reset` there, much as you would do it in your own repository, to force their Git to forget that commit.  In this case, having removed your own Git repository is ... overkill, but not necessarily *bad*.)

#### Shallow clones

> [and] I am trying to ... remove all the old commits from my pc

As noted above, that's not really how Git is designed to work.  But, if you really want, you can use what Git calls a *shallow clone*, which is a clone where the history—the commits obtained from some other Git—only go back so far.  To make a shallow clone, you would use `git clone --depth=<n> <url>` or `git clone --shallow-since=<date> url`.  Shallow clones have some restrictions as to what you can do with them, though modern Git (2.x) has removed some of the more draconian restrictions still present in older Gits.

A shallow clone, once made, can be deepened or further en-shallowed (if that's a verb) using options to `git fetch`; see [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html).

Comment: Thanks for your thoroughly explanation. I was able to delete the uselles commit using git clone ssh adress, git reset --hard head~1 and git push --force origin master. While running git clone I saw the parameter --depth that creates a shallow copy and then used it. I will read the git fetch documentation now.